# Sockets disconnected automatically in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets, serversocket, keep-alive

I created a Socket and a ServerSocket objects in as3, then I connected the socket using the connect method by passing to it a host and a port. Also I made the ServerSocket object listening for incoming connection from socket other than the socket I've just created. When the ServerSocket detects a connection and start receiving data, the socket object is disconnected automatically. So I want to know how to keep the connection alive in the socket object..

Comment: Sounds like a security issue to me... Does your server have a cross-domain policy?

Comment: I believe @weltraumpirat is right on the money here. Most likely a security issue. You need to ensure that when the connecting socket requests the socket security policy file that you're serving it up, as you should. I'll link to an answer that will solve this for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm posting this as an answer rather than just referencing this question as a duplicate because your issue is not exactly the same as the question and answer I'm going to reference here. The answer I'm linking to however provides resources that will help you understand the security model behind connecting sockets, which I believe is the issue here:

[air 2.6 serversocket and actionscript 3 socket connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638800/air-2-6-serversocket-and-actionscript-3-socket-connection/9641741#9641741)

An excerpt from the linked resource which demonstrates a "handshake" where the policy file is passed to the connecting socket:

```
private function handshakeHandler( event:ProgressEvent ):void
{
    var socket:Socket = event.target as Socket;

    //Read the message from the socket
    var message:String = socket.readUTFBytes( socket.bytesAvailable );
    logCallback( "Received: " + message);
    if( message == "" )
    {
        var policy:String = '\x00';
        socket.writeUTFBytes( policy );
        socket.flush();
        socket.close();
        logCallback("Sending policy: " + policy);
    } else if ( message == "BEGIN" )
    {
        socket.removeEventListener( ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, handshakeHandler );
        socket.addEventListener( ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, socketDataHandler );
        socket.writeUTFBytes( "READY" );
        socket.flush();
    } 
}
```

> The policy file used in this example is:

```
<cross-domain-policy>
    <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="8087" />
    </cross-domain-policy>\x00
```